# How to format date on Laravel get request

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I know its possible to format the date in laravel on the elequent query but I can't remember, how do I change the date that comes as 2022-03-31T14:51:51.000000Z to 14:51:51 2022-03-31 on the eloquent model query?

example of current query is below:

```
response()->json(
        Comment::with('user:id,username')
                ->select('id', 'comment', 'user_id', 'created_at')
                ->where('post_id', $id)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
                ->paginate(5)
    );
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can use Carbon like this : \Carbon\Carbon::parse($created_at)->format('d-m-Y  H:MM');

Answer (score 0):

You can either parse date value coming from request by: 
`$date = Carbon::parse($request->date)->format('your format params')` 
or in modern Laravel framework you can use `$request->date('date')` which create carbon instance and you can apply any carbon function.